# Set undefined parameters via arguments

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to write a function that corrects the `arguments` of a `function` based on previously specified optional parameters. I've come to a problem though. It seems that I can't set variables via the `arguments` array unless they have been defined in any way before. The code below shows an example of the problem I'm facing.

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    arguments[0] = "lorem";
    arguments[1] = "ipsum";
    arguments[2] = "dolor";

    console.log([a, b, c]);
}

foo(null);              // ["lorem", undefined, undefined]
foo(null, null);        // ["lorem", "ipsum",   undefined]
foo(null, null, null);  // ["lorem", "ipsum",   "dolor"]
```

When logging `arguments` the result is always `["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]` though.
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

I can't set `a`, `b` and `c` directly because a function called in `foo` wouldn't have access to these names.
My goal would look like something like this:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    var rules = [];
    // Rule for optional parameter 1 (b)
    // If it equals true the value of b is shifted to the next parameter (c)
    rules[1] = function(val) { return val !== "ipsum"; };
    optionalize(rules);

    console.log([a, b, c]);
}

foo("lorem", "dolor"); // ["lorem", undefined, "dolor"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit peculiar, but is this what you had in mind?

```
function optionalize(fn, options) {
    var i, key, rule;
    for(i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
        key = fn.placement[i];
        rule = fn.ruleset[key];

        // If the rule exists and returns true, shift value to the right.
        if(rule && rule(options[i])) {
            options[i+1] = options[i];
            options[i] = undefined;
        }

        // Assign the numeric index to an alphabet key.
        // Depending on your use case, you may want to substitute a plain Object here and return that, instead of adding non-numeric properties to an Array.
        options[key] = options[i];
    }
}

// Test function
function foo(a, opts) {
    opts = opts || [];
    optionalize(foo, opts);

    console.log([a, opts.b, opts.c]);
}

// Optional argument names, in the order that they would be received.
foo.placement = ['b', 'c'];

// Optionalize rules
foo.ruleset = {
    b: function (val) { return val !== "ipsum"; }
};


// Demonstration
foo('lorem');
foo('lorem', []);
foo('lorem', ['dolor']);
foo('lorem', ['ipsum', 'dolor']);
```

As dystroy's answer has already indicated, the `arguments` variable isn't a real Array, and changing it may not be a good idea. I have provided a solution which does not rely on `arguments` and fulfills the criteria as far as could be possible using simple JavaScript.

The function `foo` is specified with a required argument `a`, followed by an Array of optional arguments named `opts`. An optionalize specification is set onto `foo`, through the `placement` and `ruleset` properties. The optionalize function takes this information and transforms the array's indices into usable name keys, applying the rules as necessary.

Comment: Yep that's a nice solution. It's a bummer that we have to use an extra array though. I'm sure there is some other way to accomplish this. I'll mark this as the answer for now, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `arguments` array isn't really an array but [an "array-like" object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). You can't change its length.

What you try to do is usually done using

```
a = a || "lorem";
```

or, if you don't want to replace any "falsy" argument, using

```
if (typeof a === "undefined") a = "lorem";
```

Comment: I need to change the variables directly via the arguments array.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you think you have to do so? Because it doesn't seem like a good idea to me, even if it worked.

Comment: I'm aware of this method. It gets quite complex though if you have mutlple optional parameters. I edited my answer, this should make my concern a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but something like arguments[0] = a ? a : "lorem" and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert arguments to an array

```
function foo () {
     var arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     arguments.push(4);
     console.log(arguments);
}
foo(1,2,3);
```

​